# FSM - aiogram | How to get file?

Tags: python, state-machine, fsm, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text_contains='Send file')
async def start_bots(msg):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, 'Ok, send me a file')
    await HZ.getFile.set()



@dp.message_handler(state=HZ.getFile)
async def getID(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    file_id = msg.document.file_id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    print(file_path)
    await state.finish()
```

It doesn't cares my file, how to download file when user sent message like Send file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=HZ.getFile, content_types=['document'])
async def getID(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    file_id = msg.document.file_id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    print(file_path)
    await state.finish()
```

Таким образом aiogram будет понимать, что при вызове состояния нужно ожидать документ.

Все при помощи: `content_types=['document']`